# Remove directions from google map api

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I created in Ionic with Google map API, app that shows direction from place A to B.
But I don't know how to clean it from the map.

I have got a button that starts  startNavigating()

here is my .ts function of this:

```html
 startNavigating(){

    let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    

    directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(this.directionsPanel.nativeElement);

    directionsService.route({
        origin: this.StartN,
        destination: this.EndN,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode['DRIVING']
    }, (res, status) => {

        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(res);
        } else {
            console.warn(status);
        }

    });

    let mapOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
    }; 

  
}
```

I would like to create a button which would start "clean()" and would remove this direction.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
```

Comment: where should I put it, and How could I use it?

Comment: Sorry, but I am pretty new in Ionic and Google maps API

Comment: You can put that line in your `clean` function. However, you need to make `directionsDisplay` a global variable so that you can access it from both your `startNavigating` and `clean` functions.

Comment: put inside your method clean;

clean(){
  directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
}